# javascript scroll when remove elements Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, scroll

i've done a simple code that when i scroll down i load more data and i append new div to a parent div..when i reach a number of div that i had appended i remove previous div, it works quite well except for the fact that the app keep the scroll to the last element, so if i reach element 20, i load other 10 elements at the bottom but i remove 10 elements at the top so the user jump from element 20 to element 30.

here's my code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       var divvo=document.getElementById("content");
       var ultimo;
       for(var i=0;i<=9;i++){

       if(i+window.count<=window.gvariabile.length){
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.setAttribute('class', 'ccc'); 
       var ccc=i+window.count;
       div.setAttribute('id', 'd'+ccc); 
       //alert(i+window.count);
       div.innerHTML="<img src='img/eng_ico.jpg' class='logo'> <h3>"+window.gvariabile[i+window.count]+"</h3><p>Dettagli</p><hr class='hor'>";
       div.addEventListener("click", redirect_click(i+window.count), false);
       ultimo=ccc;
       divvo.appendChild(div);    
           }
       }
       alert($(window).scrollTop());
       if(window.count>=20)
       {
       alert("cancella");
       var parente=document.getElementById("content");
       for(var k=0;k<=9;k++){
           var rem=(window.count-20);
           var rem2=rem+k;

           var divvv = document.getElementById("d"+rem2);

           parente.removeChild(divvv);
           }

       }
      // window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById("d"+ultimo+"")));
       window.count=window.count+10;

   }
});
```

and then the html where i append:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="background"></div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by saving the scroll before deleting elements and set the scroll after deleting the elements:

```
 var scrollino=$(window).scrollTop();

       if(window.count>=20)
       {

       var parente=document.getElementById("content");
       for(var k=0;k<=9;k++){
           var rem=(window.count-20);
           var rem2=rem+k;

           var divvv = document.getElementById("d"+rem2);

           parente.removeChild(divvv);
           }
       window.scroll(0,scrollino);
       }

       window.count=window.count+10;
```